# A full math history encyclopedia. Is there one?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

Is there a book or a site or a periodic or a encyclopedia or something like this that's a

> complete reference in math history, talking about all known mathematicians and their achievements, not saving pages?

For example, a encyclopedia who talks about `Euler` and his achievements, not saving pages to talk about him?

I have the Carl Benjamin Boyer book and had seen some websites, but didn't find what I'm looking for yet. If anyone knows a good place to get knowledgment about math history, mathematicians and their achievements please I would like to know.

Comment: Does the Princeton companion to mathematics discuss the lives of mathematicians? It certainly has a lot to say about mathematics.

Comment: I would say that you won't find much better than http://www.gap-system.org/~history/ + Wikipedia online.

Comment: I would say that there is not going to be any encyclopedia that does not save pages to talk about him, as you said.  The Mac History recommended by t.b. probably has a ton of information in general.  Wikipedia probably also has quite a bit on many topics.  But, on any one specific topic, neither will be exhaustive.  If you want more information on a topic, you would probably want to buy a book on that topic.  For example, Euler.  There are full books about him.  No encyclopedia would have a full book worth of info on Euler.

Comment: And, Dickson's History of the Theory of Numbers is pretty good if you want just number theory.  It's 3 volumes, probably 1500 pages total or so.

Comment: Looks like a really good this Dickson book. I'll take a look.

Comment: When I wrote not saving pages it's because I would like to know almost all achivements done by an specific mathematician, not only superficial text. This gap-system.org it's a good site and can help us a lot, is there other interesting ones?